# Facebook login window appears and disappears without logging in the app

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk

I have created a facebook app using Javascript SDK. It works fine for me (maybe because the app is linked to my account), but it doesn't work for other users. When the user clicks on the login button, the dialog appears and ask for user's facebook username and password. But then the dialog disappears and the login button is still there. When the user click the Login button again or refresh the page, the dialog box appears and disappears very quickly. The user does get logged into his facebook account, but he does not get logged into the app.

Here is the code sample:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }); 
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    userData = response;
    document.getElementById('name').value=userData.name;
    document.getElementById('email').value=userData.email;


    });

  }

  function submit(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    userData = response;
    console.log(userData);
    var form = $("#login-form form");
    var serializedData=form.serialize()+'&id='+userData.id+'&email='+userData.email;
    console.log(serializedData);
    $.ajax({
    url: './abc.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: serializedData,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (response) {},
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){}


    }); });
  return false;
  }

  function logout(){
  FB.logout(function(response) {
        // Person is now logged out
        console.log('You have logged out of Bookatdoor. Thank you!');
        location.reload();
    });

  }
  </script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to
  present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.

  Learn more about options for the login button plugin:
  /docs/reference/plugins/login/ -->

<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
<br>
<div id="login-form">
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="submit();return false;">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" disabled>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
Re-Password: <input type="password" placeholder="Re-Type Password">
College: <select name="college">
<?php 
include "./connect.php";
$query="select * from college";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['ID']."'>".$row['NAME']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

</form>
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
<button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same situation on me, the login dialog appears and disappears immediately.

The reason is probably the sandbox mode of app (you can check it in basic settings of the app) is enabled.

It will make your app can only be used by developers. (I'm not pretty sure if your friends are also developer can still use or not)

Just turn it off, disable it, then it works for others.
This method works for me, wish works for you too.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. Yes, the sandbox mode of the app was actually the reason. It's working now. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because I was asking for a wrong permission:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,name,user_likes'});
```

removing 'name' solved it...

Comment: This was exactly my problem as well (in my case it was "birthday"). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
i had the same issue many times...when the application was still in in sandboxmode..

Check if the APP is still in Sandboxmode and check console for any errors....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: How to get reputation without answering..?

Comment: Well, in fact my comment was automatically generated in a review. Anyway, you will earn reputation by answering questions (and also asking), but you have to provide good responses to be upvoted! This answer of yours isn't good at all... (starting with a *note*, not providing a solution, unnecesary "good luck" comment, and so on...)

Comment: difficult to ask for more information or giving hints to try... when i can´t comment posts

Comment: Yes, you can't post comments and that limits you a bit, but you can still provide a good answer IF YOU REALLY KNOW THE SOLUTION, and you can ask a good question, about an interesting issue and with a good formatting and so on... and you'll gain rep. Moreover you can suggest edits on posts and earn +2 rep for each approved edit...

Comment: like so? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993885/check-child-window-focus-in-javascript

Comment: thanks @delueg. that helped. it should have made sense to me in the first place when it was not allowing anyone but me (the admin).

Answer (score 1):

If you already gave permission and your app is in the `development mode` then the popup immediately disappears.

*Recommended:* You may remove permission from `Facebook > Settings > Business Integrations`

*Optional:* You may switch your app to `Live` but if you didn't send your app to `Review` for required permissions then you'll get a permission error.